Issues with Exporting a table cell
I can't seem to export my datasets properly.
The code below shows:
polytopedataset = Table[generateRandomPolytope[],{10}]
Export["matrices.dat",polytopedataset]
SystemOpen["matrices.dat"]

But when I open it, I see this error:

I don't understand why it isn't just exporting to my directory? Any help would be great here.
